# Dual-boot system and NTFS access

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I have a dual-boot system - Ubuntu 18.04.3 + Windows XP. My Windows XP installation has been set up long time ago with `Administrator` user and a number of non-privileged users - and it's good because regular users can't modify or destroy important system files by mistake.

However all this foolproof setup is wasted when I login into Ubuntu - I can easily mount the Windows XP system disk `C:` and make any changes there I want, even without `sudo`. For example, I can remove **any** Windows XP drivers...

As far as I know the [ntfs-3g](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/mount.ntfs-3g.8.html) driver is normally used for access from Ubuntu to Windows XP. My driver version:

```
hekto@ubuntu:~$ dpkg -l | grep ntfs
ii  libntfs-3g88                           1:2017.3.23-2ubuntu0.18.04.2          amd64        read/write NTFS driver for FUSE (runtime library)
ii  ntfs-3g                                1:2017.3.23-2ubuntu0.18.04.2          amd64        read/write NTFS driver for FUSE
```

The Windows XP system partition is normally **not** mounted, and it's not in the `/etc/fstab` file. I used to mount it by double-clicking on its icon in the Ubuntu GUI. The mounted partition is reported in Ubuntu as:

```
hekto@ubuntu:~$ mount | grep Windows
/dev/sda1 on /media/hekto/Windows type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Permissions for some critical Windows XP system files, visible from Ubuntu:

```
hekto@ubuntu:~$ ll /media/hekto/Windows/WINDOWS/system32/*.sys
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hekto hekto    9029 Aug  4  2004 /media/hekto/Windows/WINDOWS/system32/ansi.sys*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hekto hekto   27097 Aug  4  2004 /media/hekto/Windows/WINDOWS/system32/country.sys*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hekto hekto    4768 Aug  4  2004 /media/hekto/Windows/WINDOWS/system32/himem.sys*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hekto hekto   42809 Aug  4  2004 /media/hekto/Windows/WINDOWS/system32/key01.sys*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hekto hekto   42537 Aug  4  2004 /media/hekto/Windows/WINDOWS/system32/keyboard.sys*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hekto hekto   29146 Aug  4  2004 /media/hekto/Windows/WINDOWS/system32/ntdos404.sys*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hekto hekto   29370 Aug  4  2004 /media/hekto/Windows/WINDOWS/system32/ntdos411.sys*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hekto hekto   29274 Aug  4  2004 /media/hekto/Windows/WINDOWS/system32/ntdos412.sys*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hekto hekto   29146 Aug  4  2004 /media/hekto/Windows/WINDOWS/system32/ntdos804.sys*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hekto hekto   27866 Aug  4  2004 /media/hekto/Windows/WINDOWS/system32/ntdos.sys*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hekto hekto   34560 Aug  4  2004 /media/hekto/Windows/WINDOWS/system32/ntio404.sys*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hekto hekto   35648 Aug  4  2004 /media/hekto/Windows/WINDOWS/system32/ntio411.sys*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hekto hekto   35424 Aug  4  2004 /media/hekto/Windows/WINDOWS/system32/ntio412.sys*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hekto hekto   34560 Aug  4  2004 /media/hekto/Windows/WINDOWS/system32/ntio804.sys*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hekto hekto   33840 Aug  4  2004 /media/hekto/Windows/WINDOWS/system32/ntio.sys*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hekto hekto   17664 Apr 14  2008 /media/hekto/Windows/WINDOWS/system32/watchdog.sys*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hekto hekto 1845632 Apr 14  2008 /media/hekto/Windows/WINDOWS/system32/win32k.sys*
```

I want to prohibit writing to the Windows XP system partition from Ubuntu *at all* - only in some rare cases I need to read something from this partition to Ubuntu, and I never write from Ubuntu to the Windows XP system partition.

What's the best and simplest way to do that?

Comment: You actually want to mount in fstab, so you can set permissions. With Windows types only defaults from mounting apply. You can use noauto so not automatically mounted and set permissions so not allowed. Or you can use ro for read only. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/858029/how-to-disable-access-to-win7-disk-partitiondual-boot/858105#858105

Comment: @oldfred - my `/etc/fstab` doesn't contain `NTFS` partitions... Thank you for the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question. The best and simplest way (for me) to do that was to create a [udisks](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/udisks/) configuration file `/etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf` with following two lines:

```
[/dev/disk/by-label/Windows]
defaults=ro
```

The Ubuntu still reports `rwxrwxrwx` permissions for all files and directories on this partition, however it's a lie - the partition becomes read-only,

Answer (score 1):

How about running `umount /mnt/windows` every time a user logs in, or renaming `ntfs-3g` so users can't access it (but you know the real name of that executable)?

Comment: Thank you for editing... However, all the Windows partitions aren't mounted by default, and any of them can be easily mounted by double-click on the corresponding icon - that's the problem, it's too easy and very unsafe. The directory `/mnt/windows` is always empty. Your idea about renaming looks like last resort - I'll try it, thanks, but I'd like to play with permissions at first